# How to set a default value for null values in JMESPath query when using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli, jmespath

I'm trying to run a command with AWS CLI with query. The command could be something simple like `aws s3api list-buckets --query 'sum(Versions[*].Size)'`

However, occasionally, some values can return null. In the example above, size can be null when there is nothing and the command will return the following error:

`In function sum(), invalid type for value: None, expected one of: ['array-number'], received: "null"`

How can I give it a default value? If the actual value is null, I would like to set it to `0` so that there is some value in the result instead of an error.

Comment: You can try `sum(Versions[*].Size || 0)`

Comment: @Marcin I have tried that but it returns an error that `invalid token: Parse error at column 20, token "0" (NUMBER)`

Comment: And this version `'sum(Versions[*].Size || [\`0\`])'`? Note back-quotes around 0.

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind, I provided an answer for future reference.

Comment: @Marcin Absolutely!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The solution was to use:

```
aws s3api list-buckets --query 'sum(Versions[*].Size || [`0`])'
```